# Why can I not import Tensorflow.contrib I get an error of No module named 'tensorflow.python.saved

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I just installed `Tensorflow` on my Mac and I want to use `tf.contrib.slim` but when I use it I get this

```
import tensorflow as tf

slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

Error:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/export/export_lib.py", line 25, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils import build_all_signature_defs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils'

I don't know what to do, please help me

I use `Tensorflow.13.1` and `python 3.7`

Answer (score 83):

For anyone who is trying some old codes from ***github*** with `Tensorflow 1.x.x` versions while having `Tensorflow 2.0.x` please note that `tf.contrib` no longer exist in `Tensorflow 2.0.x` and it's modules were moved.
Please google the name of the module without the `tf.contrib` part to know it's new location and thus migrating your code accordingly by correcting the `import` statement.

*Hope this helped!*

Comment: Classic reply, but IMHO not so helpful, at least in my case.

For some GPT-2 model I have an error in:
    from tensorflow.contrib.training import HParams
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Should I google for "tensorflow" :) ?

(I think I need to upgrade the code, since I am on apple silicon w/  tf. __version__, '2.11.0').

Answer (score 51):

first unistall tensorflow

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

then install 1.13.2 version

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.2
```

it works.. had the same issue.. but installing tensorflow 1.13.2 solved it!
the newer version of tensorflow doesn't have

Comment: Thanks, but want to mention that `tf.contrib` also exists in version 1.14. [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32229#issuecomment-528459764)

Comment: i tried it but it says ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.2

Comment: Same. Why can't we install old versions?

Comment: Because of your python version. For example, python 3.8 requires a version of tensorflow 2.2 or more.  See pip system requirements for tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements)

Answer (score 22):

first:

```
pip install --upgrade tf_slim
```

then:

```
import tf_slim as slim
```

Answer (score 12):

If the following command doesn't work

```py
pip3 install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

then we can try the following command

```py
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by below method.

```
  pip uninstall tensorflow_estimator
  pip install tensorflow_estimator
```

the reference is : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27079

Answer (score 7):

Currently the default install of tensorflow is 2.x while your code is for 1.x.
The contrib module has been removed from tf 2.x. Check the warnings:

"The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0"

Uninstall tensorflow and then install the 1.x version with

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

Comment: Works nicely. Sidenote: when I ran the command I got three lines like this `ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 2.2.0 has requirement gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.2.2 which is incompatible.` not sure why since I am removing the 2.x version.

Comment: ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Answer (score 3):

tf.contrib has moved out of TF starting TF 2.0 alpha.

You can upgrade your TF 1.x code to TF 2.x using the tf_upgrade_v2 script https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the [Migration Guide from TensorFlow 1.x to TensorFlow 2 page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), install [TF-Slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim), available on Google-research Github page and then use

```
import tf_slim as slim
```

instead of `tf.contrib.layers`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using following steps:

First i do check current version of my tf
using

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

```
2.5.0
```

Then contrib is part of older version of tensorflow as it removed from 2.X.

so we need to use tf version 1.X

that will be done using following snippet

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

and you will get output

```
**TensorFlow 1.x selected.
1.15.2**
```

now you can use

```
from tensorflow.contrib import seq2seq
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import DropoutWrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing the code may be a bit tedious but if you are willing to make the effort - just add this in all tensorflow links

```
compat.v1
```

so `tf.assign -> tf.compat.v1.assign`

etc

Answer (score 1):

Contrib has been taken from tensorflow in 2.x version we have to switch to an older version.

If you are using in collab you can directly switch from 2.x version to 1.x with this command

`%tensorflow_version 1.x`

Doing this solved the problem.

Apart from collab you can just uninstall your current version and install 1.15.2 with the following commands.

`pip uninstall tensorflow`

`pip install tensorflow==1.15.2`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers, tensorflow.contrib is not supported in tensorflow 2. I fixed the problem with creating an environment in conda with its python version set to 3.7 and setting tensorflow version to 1.14. You may face a one or two bugs related to package compatibility but eventually it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think majority of solution is suggesting to downgrade tensorflow version. At first place why does TF 2 does not support WALS factorization?One blog suggest its because official recommendataion is NCF [Matrix Factorization in tensorflow 2.0 using WALS Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902387/matrix-factorization-in-tensorflow-2-0-using-wals-method).

Answer (score -4):

Starting from tensorflow 13.1 there's no contrib. You can use without it `slim = tf.slim` or you can install `pip install tensorflow==1.13` and use it

Comment: add link to the reference material/documentation

Answer (score -5):

for running it on python3 I used pip3 to install

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

This worked for me