# Matrix Factorization in tensorflow 2.0 using WALS Method

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, matrix-factorization

I am using WALS method in order to perform matrix factorization. Initially in tensorflow 1.13 I can import factorization_ops using

```
from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops import factorization_ops
```

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-recommendation-wals/blob/master/wals_ml_engine/trainer/wals.py)

Wals model can be called from factorization_ops by using

```
factorization_ops.WALSModel
```

Using same command in tensorflow 2.0 giving me following error

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.factorization**

Going through the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350) there appears to be no way out to use WALSModel in tensorflow 2.0+.

Also it has been mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) in tensorflow release updates that tf.contrib has been deprecated, and functionality has been either migrated to the core TensorFlow API, to an ecosystem project such as tensorflow/addons or tensorflow/io, or removed entirely.

How can I use WALS model in tensorflow 2.0 (Currently I am using 2.0.0-rc0 on windows machine) ? Is WALSModel has been removed or I am missing out some information ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe WALS is not supported in TF 2.0 ...The official recommendation model is [Neural Collaborative Filter (NCF)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/08bb9eb5ad79e6bceffc71aeea6af809cc78694b/official/recommendation)

I hope this helps.

M

Comment: Thanks this will be helpful in other way :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, but I don't really have time to write a library myself unfortunately. There are several potential options that I am considering:

1. Stick with TF1.X until someone creates a library
2. Switch to using lightfm to continue using WALS
3. Switch to neural collaborative filtering using embedding layers with keras and a dot product layer. See this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05031, and this code implementation:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Flatten, Dot, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
#import tensorflow.distribute

def get_compiled_model(n_users, n_items, embedding_dims=20):
    # Product embedding
    prod_input = Input(shape=[1], name="Item-Input")
    prod_embedding = Embedding(n_items+1, embedding_dims, name="Item-Embedding")(prod_input)
    prod_vec = Flatten(name="Flatten-Product")(prod_embedding)

    # User embedding
    user_input = Input(shape=[1], name="User-Input")
    user_embedding = Embedding(n_users+1, embedding_dims, name="User-Embedding")(user_input)
    user_vec = Flatten(name="Flatten-Users")(user_embedding)

    # The output is the dot product of the two, i.e. a one-hot vector
    dot_product = Dot(name="Dot-Product", axes=1)([prod_vec, user_vec])

    # compile - uncomment these two lines to make training distributed
    # dist_strat = distribute.Strategy()
    # with dist_strat.scope():
    model = Model(inputs = [user_input, prod_input], outputs = dot_product)
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='mean_squared_error'
    )
    return model
```

Answer (score 2):

I have compared the Tensorflow implementation of WALS to other implementations with respect to compute resources and accuracy (https://github.com/gtsoukas/cfzoo). The comparison suggests that the *implicit* Python package (https://github.com/benfred/implicit) is a good replacement that delivers superior performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that WALS has been removed. As part of `tf.contrib` it is not supported by TF2 and I do not think it fits in any of core or sub-projects.
Your best bet is probably to make it available as a third-party library.

I expect to use it for my project, but the need to re-write it (mainly copy what was in TF1 and make it work as a separate library compatible with TF2) reduce the priority of this task...

Let us know if you start to code something. Thanks.

Alexis.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to write this in case they will discontinue that as I have deployed one in TF 1.13. There is a bug opened for the same. Waiting for their final declaration. Seems like we are on same page. You want to collaborate ?