# I am working on my AI Chatbot project using conda python 3.6.9. I am getting the following errors. How to fix the following error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am making an AI Chatbot using python.

I had installed all the required pip packages:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy 
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json


with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

Expected :

> (VCB) C:\Users\Aravind Nallajerla\Desktop\Capstone Project\VCB>python
>   main.py

```
{
    'intents': [{
        'tag': 'greeting',
        'patterns': ['Hi', 'How are you', 'Is anyone there?', 'Hello', 'Good day', 'Whats up'],
        'responses': ['Hello!', 'Good to see you again!', 'Hi there, how can I help?'],
        'context_set': ''
    }, {
        'tag': 'goodbye',
        'patterns': ['cya', 'See you later', 'Goodbye', 'I am Leaving', 'Have a Good day'],
        'responses': ['Sad to see you go :(', 'Talk to you later', 'Goodbye!'],
        'context_set': ''
    }, {
        'tag': 'age',
        'patterns': ['how old', 'how old is tim', 'what is your age', 'how old are you', 'age?'],
        'responses': ['I am 18 years old!', '18 years young!'],
        'context_set': ''
    }, {
        'tag': 'name',
        'patterns': ['what is your name', 'what should I call you', 'whats your name?'],
        'responses': ['You can call me Tim.', "I'm Tim!", "I'm Tim aka Tech With Tim."],
        'context_set': ''
    }, {
        'tag': 'shop',
        'patterns': ['Id like to buy something', 'whats on the menu', 'what do you reccommend?', 'could i get something to eat'],
        'responses': ['We sell chocolate chip cookies for $2!', 'Cookies are on the menu!'],
        'context_set': ''
    }, {
        'tag': 'hours',
        'patterns': ['when are you guys open', 'what are your hours', 'hours of operation'],
        'responses': ['We are open 7am-4pm Monday-Friday!'],
        'context_set': ''
    }]
}
```

Actual :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 6, in
>   
>       import tflearn   File "C:\Users\Aravind Nallajerla\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\VCB\lib\site-packages\tflearn__init__.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from . import config   File "C:\Users\Aravind Nallajerla\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\VCB\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       from .variables import variable   File "C:\Users\Aravind Nallajerla\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\VCB\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.contrib

Comment: what is the tensorflow version... this can be found using `print(tensorflow.__version__)`

Comment: check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082483/why-i-cannot-import-tensorflow-contrib-i-get-an-error-of-no-module-named-tensor

Comment: and this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350

Answer (score 0):

uninstall latest tensorflow, it don't have -contrib module.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

then, Try this older version.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You must install the tensorflow module, with `pip install tensorflow`
in the terminal.

If there are errors in the pip installation, then try changing the python version or refer to the [official error list](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).