# no module found : tensorflow.contrib

Tags: openpose

trying to run openpose on windows.
tensorflow = 1.14 installed already.
getting the error no module found : tensorflow.contrib
is there any way to work out on this on windows?
or any other library to work for pose detection?

Please suggest a alternate way to do pose estimation if there is no solution to this problem for windows.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is already here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082483/why-i-cannot-import-tensorflow-contrib-i-get-an-error-of-no-module-named-tensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got above error because ***tensorflow.contrib*** has been removed from the packages.

Since all the projects in [tf.contrib](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) were not officially supported by Tensorflow and it had designated owners for maintaining it.

From Tensorflow 2.x version all the contrib projects has three options: ***move to core***, ***move to a separate repository*** or ***delete*** most of of them have been reviewed with the respective project owners.

If the library you are using is moved to the core or separate repository, then tensorflow automatic code migration from `1.x` to `2.x` will not work for tf.contrib` projects.  You have to change code manually for above parts, which is suggested going forward.

You can refer [this](https://medium.com/@gsethi2409/pose-estimation-with-tensorflow-2-0-a51162c095ba) article for Pose Estimation using TensorFlow 2.0.