# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 but getting error while executing train.py.

from tensorflow.contrib.memory_stats.python.ops.memory_stats_ops import BytesInUse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

can anyone please help me with finding tf.contrib module in tensorflow2.0

Comment: Does the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082483/why-i-cannot-import-tensorflow-contrib-i-get-an-error-of-no-module-named-tensor help you ?

Comment: there is an entire github issue about this topic https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350

Answer (score 2):

`tensorflow.contrib` is being removed in version 2.0, you therefore need version <= 1.14 to operate tflearn (by the way, this is a TFlearn issue, not a tensorflow one). ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30794#issuecomment-512188521))