# Object Detection Google Colab: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I've been working on codes for Object Detection in Google Colab as in [1](https://medium.com/hackernoon/object-detection-in-google-colab-with-custom-dataset-5a7bb2b0e97e) and in [2](https://medium.com/swlh/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-with-google-colab-b2af171e81cc) but, when using the following code sample:

```
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-tk

!pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib PyDrive

!pip install -q pycocotools

!pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api

%cd ~/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I'm obtaining this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 22, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.predictors import convolutional_box_predictor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/predictors/convolutional_box_predictor.py", line 22, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

How can I use 'contrib' and other tensorflow v1 attributes with tensorflow v2?
Appreciate any kind of help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code like the following, and confirmed it throws no exception on Colaboratory (CPU backend). It is weird that I did not get the `contrib` error you mentioned...

Gist: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/yumemio/343d342898b2e7c396967477b1756cf5/so_q71844660.ipynb

```
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-tk

!pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib PyDrive

!pip install -q pycocotools

!pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api

!pip install tf_slim tensorflow_io   # added

%cd /content/models/research   # modified
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/:/content/models/'   # modified

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

---

> How can I use 'contrib' and other tensorflow v1 attributes with tensorflow v2?

You cannot use `contrib` in TF2.x, since [it was deprecated and removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130063/13301046). [TensorFlow v1 and v2 are quite different](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2), and it is hard, if not impossible, to make the two versions' behaviours coexist.

The Object Detection framework provides support for both TF1 and TF2, although [the maintainers recommend the latter](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection#support-for-tensorflow-2-and-1). Since the second article you linked targets TF2.x, I would recommend you to stick to TF2.

If you need to use TF1.x, you can use [`%tensorflow_version` magic command](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb) to switch to TF1.x.

```
# Use TF1.x (available only in Colab)
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```